# How to read connections at the same time using select? sockets/c

Tags: c, sockets, select

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int port = 3008;
int listenfd;

extern void makelistener();
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    makelistener();
    int clientfd, nready;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in q;
    int i;

    // initialize allset and add listenfd to the
    // set of file descriptors passed into select
    fd_set allset;
    fd_set rset;
    int maxfd;
    FD_ZERO(&allset);
    FD_SET(listenfd, &allset); // set of file descriptors

    maxfd = listenfd;
    int ret;

    while (1)
    {
        // make a copy of the set before we pass it into select
        rset = allset;
        /*select will wait until an exceptional event occurs when tv is NULL*/


        nready = select(maxfd + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (nready == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (nready == -1) {
            perror("select");
            continue;
        }

        //FD_ISSET returns 1 when a new connection is attempted
        if(FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset)){
            //printf("a new client is connecting\n");
            len = sizeof(q); //accept connection of listenfd stream socket
            if ((clientfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&q, &len)) < 0) {
                perror("accept");
                exit(1);
            }
            FD_SET(clientfd, &allset);
            if (clientfd > maxfd) {
                maxfd = clientfd;
            }

            static char msg[] = "What is your name?\r\n";
            write(clientfd, msg, sizeof msg - 1);
            printf("connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(q.sin_addr));
            char buf[256];
            ret = read(clientfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
            buf[ret] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buf);
       }



   }





}


void makelistener()
{
    struct sockaddr_in r;

    if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&r, '\0', sizeof r);
    r.sin_family = AF_INET;
    r.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    r.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&r, sizeof r)) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    };

    if (listen(listenfd, 5)) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

above code is for the server and it does this

```
$ ./above.c
(does nothing but runs forever)
```

How to connect as a client:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 3000
What is your name?
(waiting for my input) so if I put bob, it would output it to the server
```

It works as intended. But I want it too work concurrently with multiple clients.

for example:

server

```
$ ./above.c
(does nothing but runs forever)
```

client1

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 3000
What is your name?
```

client 2

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 3000
What is your name? (Currently client2 wont show up until client1 is answered which is what I'm trying to fix)
```

How do I make it so the clients can run concurrently without waiting for the first client to finish? To explain the code a little bit, listener just binds and listens to a connection. Inside the while(1) is where select and calls are.

Comment: Why don't you add `FD_ISSET` check for the connected sockets in the set? You do know that sockets by default are *blocking* which means if you call `read` on a socket without receiving anything, it will block forever (until there's an error or connection is closed). That will halt the execution of your server program, blocking all other connection attempts and putting all already connected clients data in buffers that will slowly fill up.

Comment: And if you want each connection to have a state (like possibly `STATE_GETTING_NAME`, `STATE_CHATTING`, etc. in your case), then I suggest you start learning about *structures*, and store the socket descriptor and the state in a structure, and have a list of such structures that you go through as needed.

Comment: <O/T> suffixing your executable with `.c` is quite misleading

Comment: 'At the same time' implies threads. `select()` implies sequential scanning of the FD_SET and reading the sockets accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make it so the clients can run concurrently without waiting for the first client to finish?

By paying attention to which sockets `select()` reports to you.  You are asking `select()` to monitor multiple sockets for readability, but you are only checking if the listening socket is readable, you are not checking the client sockets.  You need to keep track of the connected clients so you can enumerate them when needed.

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int port = 3008;
#define MAX_CLIENTS (FD_SETSIZE - 1)

int listenfd = -1;

extern void makelistener();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int clientfd, nready;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in q;
    int i, j, ret;
    fd_set allset;
    fd_set rset;
    int clients[MAX_CLIENTS];
    int num_clients = 0;
    int maxfd;
    char buf[256];

    makelistener();

    // initialize allset and add listenfd to the
    // set of file descriptors passed into select
    FD_ZERO(&allset);
    FD_SET(listenfd, &allset);
    maxfd = listenfd;

    while (1)
    {
        // make a copy of the set before we pass it into select
        FD_COPY(&allset, &rset);

        // select will wait until an exceptional event occurs when tv is NULL
        nready = select(maxfd + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (nready < 0) {
            perror("select");
            continue;
        }

        if (nready == 0) { // should never happen since no timeout was requested
            continue;
        }

        //FD_ISSET returns 1 when a socket is readable

        if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset)) {
            //printf("a new client is connecting\n");
            len = sizeof(q); //accept connection of listenfd stream socket
            if ((clientfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&q, &len)) < 0) {
                perror("accept");
                exit(1);
            }

            printf("Client %d connected from %s\n", clientfd, inet_ntoa(q.sin_addr));

            if (num_clients == MAX_CLIENTS) {
                static char msg[] = "Max number of clients are already connected\r\n";
                write(clientfd, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
                close(clientfd);
            }
            else {
                static char msg[] = "What is your name?\r\n";
                if (write(clientfd, msg, sizeof(msg)-1) < 0) {
                    close(clientfd);
                }
                else {
                    clients[num_clients++] = clientfd;
                    FD_SET(clientfd, &allset);
                    if (clientfd > maxfd) {
                        maxfd = clientfd;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < num_clients; ++i) {
            clientfd = clients[i];

            if (!FD_ISSET(clientfd, &rset)) {
                continue;
            }

            ret = read(clientfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
            if (ret <= 0) {
                //printf("a client has disconnected\n");
                close(clientfd);
                FD_CLR(clientfd, &allset);
                for (j = i + 1; j < num_clients; ++j) {
                    clients[j-1] = clients[j];
                }
                --num_clients;

                if (clientfd == maxfd) {
                    maxfd = listenfd;
                    for (j = 0; j < num_clients; ++j) {
                        if (clients[j] > maxfd) {
                            maxfd = clients[j];
                        }
                    }
                }

                --i;
                continue;
            }

            printf("Client %d: %.*s", clientfd, ret, buf);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `poll()` or `epoll()` would generally be a better choice to use than `select()`.

Answer (score 0):

*How do I make it so the clients can run concurrently without waiting for the first client to finish?*

every time that the call to `accept()` returns, start a thread `pthread_create()` to handle the actual communication with the client.

Note: creating/destroying a thread is very time consuming, so suggest learning about `thread pools` and how to use them.

When using threads, there is no call to `select()` (nor `poll()`)  Rather the main function gets blocked on the call to `accept()` and when that function returns, pass the associated socket to a thread to handle

There are lots of example code for how a server should communicate with multiple clients on stackoverflow.com